# How to change Pinax login template?

Tags: python, django, pinax

I'm using  pinax Theme Bootstrap ([Github link](https://github.com/pinax/pinax-theme-bootstrap)) for an app, but I would like to change the form, beucause it's all in english and I would like to turn into portuguese. So, I don't know how to change the template, because its template was not downloaded when I installed it.

I saw that is possible to change the login template navbar, but I'm referring to the form itself.

Answer (score 0):

When you install Django apps they are usually installed in your python install directory in the `site-packages` folder.

BUT you don't need to modify it, all the text in login.html has `trans` tags, so you should be able to use [internationalisation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-template-code).